# opencv imread not working but other functions are

Tags: opencv

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img = Mat::zeros(Size(60,60),CV_8UC1);
    imwrite("test.bmp", img);
    Mat img2 = imread("Screw.png");
    namedWindow("image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("image", img);
    imshow("img", img2);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Opencv 3.4.6 with visual studio 2015.

I am unable to read any image from system, have tried png and jpg image format.To make sure that image is in the right location I have also used imwrite function to save an blank image, which is working fine.

I have tried opencv 4.0.1 as well giving the same issue.

Comment: I think you need to replace all your include statements with `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

Comment: This is using pre-built binaries from OpenCV website? | "I am unable to read any image from system" -- what exactly does that mean? Does it crash? if so, what's the error? | Given that your `imwrite` and `imread` use a different file name (and there's no verification in the code to test whether either of them succeeds), there's little evidence provided that the image you're trying to read exists in the working directory, and is in a correct format. | Why all those useless includes? The example should be **minimal**.

Comment: did you try loading "test.bmp"? There you can at least be sure that the path is right.

Comment: @DanMašek have builted opencv from source. imread is returning NULL data, and   "Screw.png" is in the correct folder.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i have tried your suggestion...problem remains the same.

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio,  but I think it stores and runs your program from some directory called `Debug` or `Release` under your project directory so your image needs to be in there, or you need to use a full path like `imread('/Users/you/Desktop/screw.png'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell tried already didn't worked

Comment: Maybe you don't have the correct libraries, so try loading a PGM/PPM image which OpenCV can handle without needing any libraries to see if that is the problem. Grab one from here http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/pgma/pgma.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some issue in configuration part. There are so many tutorials available for the configuration procedure. Try below link for the configuration and also 
as @mark suggested replace your header file

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-VHaLHC4XI